# Using the spell Meteor Strike to harvest materials from a meteor

Tags: magic, materials, meteor

As the title says, i'm using my spell meteor strike to harvest metals/materials. I am able to land them on a very very large inwardly curving stone plate that neutralizes the impact of the meteor strike spell meaning there won't be devastation on the area. Only the meteor remains.

assuming that the size of meteor that the spell meteor strike is consistent at the size of Tunguska event meteor (50-190 meters).

With that in mind, how will I harvest materials from this meteor?

How much material can i harvest from this meteor?

And if you can, can you include on how will i be able to utilize those materials.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your problem. You ask how you will harvest material from the meteor, and how much, but in the post you state you have a meteor harvest spell and the size of the meteors.

Comment: You've asked 3 questions (you're only supposed to ask one): (a) how to harvest, (b) quantity of harvest and (c) how to use the harvest.  (a) is trivial: use a pick.  If you want a another answer you need to explain the tech level and/or magic rules of your world.  (b) is unanswerable: how much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood. (c) is so broad the question should be closed because of it.

Comment: If you are talking about the D&D spell Meteor Strike, it’s not really a question for Worldbuilding but the RPG stack.

Comment: Please provide the definition and details of the spell you are using. Otherwise, the answer would be, "whatever the rules that the world that you are building would allow for."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What are these falling stars?**

**[image: What are these falling stars?]**

https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/220315755/studio-ghibli-howls-moving-castle

You have a fiction with meteor magic, and you want to harvest metal?  You can do better than that!  Are the falling stars spirits or demons, torn from their homes in the sky by your spell?  Are they the bones of a dead god, longing to come home?  Are they relics of a long ago magic that you can recreate?

If the meteor is just a lump of nickel and iron you don't need to be so careful.  But if it is a thing with some sort of life you do need to be careful.  You want it intact.  And you want its friends.

Answer (score 0):

You know, a meteor hitting earth, even if it hits a stone plate, would still disintegrate pretty much completely. It's not a matter of mining into a large ball of rock; but about walking around collecting the tiny shards that may contain minerals you want (I assume mostly iron, unless your civilization is very technologically advanced).